# using chosen as jquery select but its loading all values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

i am using jquery chosen plugin and it is working fine, the issue is i had two tabs ui query based which loads the jquery chosen with multiselect for both, the name of both selects are different

but in one case, i select a value and run it and open it , keeps the value and run again works fine,

when i go to the other tab, run the code and chose one value in that jquery chosen, its works first time, but next time i open same tab and it loads all the values in that jquery chosen.

what i am missing here, do i need to do a destry, but if destroy it will not keep the values.

bit lost and confused

Comment: Could you please add some code, preferably with the issue isolated?

Comment: `...bit lost and confused` ... so are we, without any context. As the previous comment suggests, need some code, preferably a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)